# Passing arguments to mysql.exe in powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, parameters, arguments

I have been tasked with converting a batch script into powershell. This batch script simply passes arguments to mysql.exe to run a query and export it into a .txt file. This works when running as a batch file, however since pasting it into powershell I get the error described below.

Code:

```
cd "C:\PS\mysql" .\mysql.exe --defaults-file=C:\PS\mysql\my.ini
--defaults-group-suffix=marketing -A -n < C:\PS\mysql\SQLGFHW.sql > C:\PS\output.txt
```

This is the error I get:

```
At C:\PS\googleCons.ps1:3 char:88
+ ... =C:\PS\mysql\my.ini --defaults-group-suffix=marketing -A -n < C:\PS\m ...
+                                                                 ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

I expected that the < operator would be a global thing and could be used on either script. Is there a different method to dealing with this in PS?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot natively redirect input in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).  One alternative is using `Start-Process`:

```
$spParams = @{
    FilePath               = 'mysql.exe'
    ArgumentList           = @(
        '--defaults-file=my.ini'
        '--defaults-group-suffix=marketing'
        '-A', '-n'
    )
    WorkingDirectory       = 'C:\PS\mysql'
    RedirectStandardInput  = 'SQLGFHW.sql'
    RedirectStandardOutput = 'C:\PS\output.txt'
    Wait                   = $true
}
Start-Process @spParams
```